# SQL join records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a invoice header table `customer_invoice_header` with primary key `cust_inv_id`

Then have a details record table `customer_invoice_item` with field `customer_invoice_header_id`

Each header has many rows, rows saved in customer_invoice_item table.

I want to write a sql to get all headers and show sum of record details. how do i do that?

I wrote:

```
SELECT cih.cust_inv_id, sum(cii.amount) as records_total 
FROM customer_invoice_header cih LEFT JOIN customer_invoice_item cii
ON cih.cust_inv_id = cii.customer_invoice_header_id
```

But it returns one record only. Even if there are 10 header records.

Do advise.

Comment: add "group by cih.cust_inv_id" at the end of your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `group by` clause at the end of the query like:

```
SELECT cih.cust_inv_id, sum(cii.amount) as records_total 
FROM customer_invoice_header cih LEFT JOIN customer_invoice_item cii
ON cih.cust_inv_id = cii.customer_invoice_header_id
GROUP BY cih.cust_inv_id
```